# Is it possible to append text to a textbox using a for each statement?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to read through each record and get the data. Is there a way I can append the text eachtime to my summarytextbox so it will show all the records/add them one by one?

```
 Dim str As String = Session("List")
 For Each s As String In str.Split(","c)
 SummaryTextBox.Text = Session("FirstName") & " " & Session("LastName")

 Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5.aspx):

```
Dim str As String = Session("List")
Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder()

For Each s In str.Split(","c)
    sb.Append(s)
Next

SummaryTextBox.Text = sb.ToString()
```

... and of course, you can use whatever format you want to display the concatenated results.

**EDIT:** Like Tim alluded to, I'm not sure what the difference between the `List` and `FirstName` and `LastName` session variables, so I'm just appending the `s` until further clarification is made by the OP.

Comment: @user1342164 No problem at all. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
Dim str As String = Session("List")
For Each s As String In str.Split(","c)
  SummaryTextBox.Text &= Session("FirstName") & " " & Session("LastName") & ", "
Next
```

Comment: Place a vbCrLf at end to add a line. TextBoxes also have an .AppendText method - not sure if it would have much benefit over the posted solution. Probably faster string handling but not enough to notice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how that list is related to the firstname and lastname. However, this might give you an idea:

```
Dim firstName = DirectCast(Session("FirstName"), String)
Dim lastName = DirectCast(Session("LastName"), String)
Dim query = From s In DirectCast(Session("List"), String).Split(","c)
            Select String.Format("{0} {1}: {2}", firstName, lastName, s)
SummaryTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Stringbuilder is the preferred method. String is immutable, therefor every time a string is appended with & " ", a new string is created. StringBuilder was designed with the purpose of having a mutable string where a variety of operations can be performed on it.